# What does this syntax mean in Haskell: _|_ or (_|_)

Tags: haskell

I keep seeing this rather embarrassing thing in many respected documents: `_|_` or `(_|_)`

Cannot find a definition of it (Google doesn't work well with symbols). So what is it anyway?

Comment: Probably http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Bottom?

Comment: Keep in mind "bottom" is a broad concept - the ascii you post is a representation of the mathematical symbol that people use in discussion but it is not actual Haskell code.  Don't type it in and expect anything to compile (use `undefined` or `error "Foo"`).

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson, I throw exception all around my code a lot, so if this is a particular representation of the bottom then I am pretty much familiar with it.

Answer (score 11):

From [here](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Bottom):-

> **Bottom**
>
> The mathematical symbol for bottom is '⊥'. That's Unicode character
>   22A5 hex = 8869 decimal. Also available in HTML as '⊥' and in
>   LaTeX as '\bot' (within math mode). In plain ASCII, it's often written
>   as the extremely ugly character sequence `'_|_'`.

Also from the [reserve keywords in Haskell](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Keywords).

Check the wiki for [Bottom and Partial Functions](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Denotational_semantics)

> To define partial functions, we introduce a special value ⊥, named
>   bottom and commonly written *|* in typewriter font. We say that ⊥ is
>   the completely "undefined" value or function. Every basic data type
>   like Integer or () contains one ⊥ besides their usual elements.

More description is given [here](http://blog.ezyang.com/2010/12/hussling-haskell-types-into-hasse-diagrams/):-

[image]

[image]

Comment: I am still very new to Haskell and this article doesn't make sense to me. What is a practical application of this thing?

Comment: @AlekseyBykov:- Just added a reference in which you can find the practical application of `_|_`

Comment: It'd be worth asking that as another question, it's a large topic. There are also already a number of SO questions on it.

Comment: the last article looks very festive with colors and stars, I will definitely read it, thank you

Comment: Concretely, you can think of Bottom representing cases like an infinite loop, where the function fails to return any value.

Comment: @comingstorm, not sure why I would need a representation of an infinite loop. I mean, where in my program can that be useful? If there is a path that doesn't know how to be finished I would throw an exception. If throwing an exception is just a particular case of the bottom concept then I guess I got it.

Comment: @AlekseyBykov Well in debugging, bottom can have any type, I often use undefined to let me "fill in the holes later"

Comment: Because of Haskell's pervasive laziness, using even a simply typed value may block due to an infinite loop.  On the other hand, this is not necessarily true of "unboxed" types (which are an optimization that I don't actually know much about).  In any case, Bottom is a useful concept for discussing computations that do not terminate normally, whether due to exception, nontermination, or blocking due to I/O...

Comment: @AlekseyBykov, this is mostly useful from theoretical point of view. Having bottoms in a type system gives nice theoretical properties, like unification of inductive and coinductive types. However, sometimes a value which is a part of any type can be useful in practice. For example, when programming in "top-to-bottom" style you can write function stubs using `undefined` (Haskell name for bottom value).

Comment: @AlekseyBykov, yes, when a function call results in throwing an exception, the value of the function call is `_|_`. Any computation that doesn't complete in the normal fashion (e.g. because of an infinite loop or because of throwing an exception) has the value of `_|_`.

Comment: @AlekseyBykov In a lazy language you might have really reasonable values like `Cons _|_ (Cons 3 Nil)` which provides partial information as to its value. We know it's a non-empty list, we know the second value is `3`, we know the length is 2. It's only explicitly inspecting the first value that causes us to get "stuck" in the infinite loop. For this reason, `_|_` is a valuable tool for reasoning about programs.

Answer (score 0):

To be clear, `_|_` is not haskell syntax, and "bottom" is a concept that's mostly useful for language designers. I think it's dubious to say, as quoted in the answer above:

> Every basic data type like Integer or () contains one ⊥ besides their usual elements."

As language users we [reason fast and loose](http://www.cse.chalmers.se/~nad/publications/danielsson-et-al-popl2006.html) about our code, and it seems to me the concept of ⊥ belongs to a different conceptual plane, and I think that's where your confusion is coming from.

It's perfectly possible to learn haskell and reason about your code in the presence of exceptions and infinite loops without ever requiring the notion of a special extra inhabitant of every type.