# Exception handling and purity in Haskell

Tags: haskell, exception, functional-programming, purely-functional, io-monad

In *The acquire-use-release cycle* section from [*Real World Haskell*](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/io-case-study-a-library-for-searching-the-filesystem.html), the type of `bracket` is shown:

> ```hs
> ghci> :type bracket
> bracket :: IO a -> (a -> IO b) -> (a -> IO c) -> IO c
> ```

Now, from the [description of `bracket`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.1.0/docs/Control-Exception.html#v:bracket), I understand that an exception might be thrown while the function of type `a -> IO c` is running. With reference to the book, this exception is caught by the calling function, via `handle`:

> ```hs
> getFileSize path = handle (\_ -> return Nothing) $
>   bracket (openFile path ReadMode) hClose $ \h -> do
>     size <- hFileSize h
>     return (Just size)
> ```

I can't help but thinking that when the exception does occur from within `bracket`'s 3rd argument, `bracket` is not returning an `IO c`.

How does this go well with purity?

I think the answer might be exactly [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40076851/how-does-the-presence-of-the-error-function-bear-on-the-purity-of-haskell), but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I can't help but thinking that when the exception does occur from within bracket's 3rd argument, bracket is not returning an `IO c`.

```
Prelude> fail "gotcha" :: IO Bool
*** Exception: user error (gotcha)
```

As you note, no `Bool` (respectively, `c`) value is produced. That's ok, because the action *does not conclude* – instead it re-raises the exception. That exception might then either crash the program, or it might be caught again somewhere else in calling code – importantly, whoever catches it will **a)** not get the result value (“the `c`”), you never do that in case of an exception; **b)** doesn't need to worry about closing the file handle, because that has already been done by `bracket`.

Comment: It might help to note that, while no `c` is being returned, the expression definitively returns a value of type `IO c` -- such values include exceptional behavior.